# Running Python packages in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am trying to run [FastPhotoStyle](https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle) on my Mac. I have a limited knowledge of Python programmming.

I've successfully opened the **Converter.py** file (after some struggle to find the correct path), but I'm really lost by the result of the first command:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

AFAIK there is no user guide. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the USAGE file? https://github.com/NVIDIA/FastPhotoStyle/blob/master/USAGE.md

Comment: Thanks! I think the commands listed in "Setup" don't work in Terminal... So I might have to run Python some other way I think

Comment: You need to make sure you have installed all the python packages and dependencies.